# Arbitrary Precision Arithmetics for Double

Tags: c

So I try to use Arbitrary Precision Arithmetics to represent double via exponent and mantissa and afterwards get the same double.

I try to get mantissa and exponent using union:

```c
typedef struct  s_arith
{
    long            mant:64;
    short           exp:15;
    char            sign:1;

}               t_arith;

union u_dbl
{
    t_arith         arith;
    long double     ldbl;
};
```

Afterwards I try to get initial double using the following formula: (-1)^S * M * 2 ^ E. But it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've got the bits laid out wrong.  But it's nearly impossible to lay them out properly in this case; using a union is not a good way of picking apart the three pieces of a floating-point quantity like `long double`.  I suggest you try using one of the `frexp` functions (specifically, [`frexpl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/frexp)): that's their job.  (Otherwise, you can use shifting and masking techniques.)

Comment: Also, `long double` isn't "arbitrary precision", it's merely "extended precision".  If you want arbitrary precision, that's a different animal.

Comment: If you pick the parts apart "by hand", you're also going to have to deal with (a) the implicit leading 1 bit and (b) the exponent bias.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 for more information.

Comment: Did you even check whether the size of your type matches that of long double?

Comment: @SteveSummit there's no hidden leading bit in x87 80-bit format (which is likely the format being tried here). But exponent bias is present, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your question:

1. > So I try to use Arbitrary Precision Arithmetics

`long double` is not arbitrary precision, it's simply *extended* precision. Arbitrary precision is a mechanism to get arbitrarily many significant digits (up to memory available), while here you only have 64.

2. > `long            mant:64;`

On a 32-bit system this won't compile, because `long` will likely be 32-bit. You should use `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` (note the unsignedness: signed bit fields can lead to surprises). And actually, this doesn't have to be a bit field if you use `uint64_t`: the type itself is exactly 64 bit wide.

3. In the x87 80-bit format, as in all IEEE 754 binary formats, exponent is biased. In particular, in the 80-bit extended precision x87 format the biased exponent to represent `1.0` is `0x3fff`. So you can't simply put a `0` in this field and expect the number to be r×2⁰.

With this in mind we can write an example with your definitions amended:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct  s_arith
{
    uint64_t        mant;
    uint16_t        exp:15;
    uint8_t         sign:1;

}               t_arith;

union u_dbl
{
    t_arith         arith;
    long double     ldbl;
};

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const uint64_t mant=0xc000000000000000;
    const int expo=5;
    const union u_dbl d={mant,0x3fff+expo,0};
    printf("%Lg\n", d.ldbl);
}
```

This outputs `48` on my system (32-bit x86 Linux with gcc), as expected — because highest two bits of the significand are set, and others cleared, and the value is 1.5×2⁵.

But actually, to portably load a floating-point number from an integer significand and an exponent, you should use the already existing function from `<math.h>` header: `ldexp`. Here's how you could do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    const uint64_t mant=0xc000000000000000;
    const int expo=5;
    const long double x=ldexp(mant, expo-63);
    printf("%Lg\n", x);
}
```

The `-63` shift here compensates for the fact that the first argument of `ldexp` is taken as the value to be multiplied by `2^(second_argument)`, instead of simply being put into the significand field of the resulting number representation.

Note also that even on x86 architecture, not all compilers have 80-bit `long double`: e.g. Microsoft ones have 64-bit `long double` — same as simply `double`.

Comment: Thank you for catching the problems with the original use of signed bit-fields.  The original code is full of subtle nightmares with its use of bit-fields. Nevermind the fundamental non-portability of bit-fields to begin with...

Comment: @AndrewHenle the nonportability of bitfields is augmented by non-portability of x87 format, support for it as `long double` by the compilers (MS ones don't support it), endianness concerns etc.. Anyway, if you are trying to manipulate representations of numbers, you should already be assuming some extent of non-portability.

Comment: Re: `uint64_t        mant:64;` relies on the implementation.  May/may not be available with various compilers.  "A bit-field shall have a type that is a ... _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type"  C17 6.7.2.1 6

Comment: @chux well, this being a bitfield is actually a useless complication (which I've now removed). More problems with this chapter would be in the other fields, which are `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` (although the latter could be `_Bool`). But anyway, if your compiler doesn't support this, first concern should be whether it even supports the 80-bit floating-point format.